# cv2.calcHist provoca error “pythonw.exe ha dejado de funcionar”

Tags: python, windows, ocr

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con OCR usando una webcam. Necesito conocer el número de pixeles negros presentes en una imagen así que he intentado utilizar la función `cv2.calcHist` pero ésta hace que python se detenga cuando ejecuto el código. Si comento las líneas 13 y 14, el código funciona bien. He implementado la función como se muestra en la documentación, así que no sé lo que está mal.

Estoy usando python 2.7 en Windows 7. Aquí está el código:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    ret, pic = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', pic)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(pic, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    pic2 = img.copy()
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(pic2, (5, 5), 0)
    ret3, th3 = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    hist = np.bincount(th3.ravel(), minlength=256)
    print "# black pixels: ", hist[0]
    cv2.imshow('th3', th3)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolví el problema utilizando la función que provee `numpy` tal como lo recomienda la documentación aunque tarda 4 veces más que la función que provee `opencv` (pregunta editada con el nuevo código).

La función implementada es ésta:

```
hist = np.bincount(th3.ravel(), minlength=256)
```

Answer (score 0):

En este tutorial puedes ver como calcular y gráficar histogramas de imágenes: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2016/05/histogramas.html

Comment: Esto no resuelve mi problema. La función para el cálculo del histograma está bien implementada pues si se ejecuta en el Shell trabaja con normalidad. No necesito graficarlo, unicamente obtener el número de pixeles negros dentro de la imagen.